# Swing application - resource clean up should be done in windowClosing or windowClosed

Tags: java, swing

In Swing application, I was wondering all the resource cleanup jobs, like : network resource shutdown, stopping thread, closing file handles...

Should it be done in [windowClosed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) or [windowClosing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `windowClosed`, because it's invoked when the window has been closed. `windowClosing` gets invoked whenever the "X" in the window corner is clicked, even if you had defined something like `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` as the closing action.

A common thing to do is to set the default closing action to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, add a `WindowClosingListener` to the window, and there show some kind of "Do you really want to quit?" message box. If yes, then dispose the window, if no, then do nothing.